# Not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

```
Uncaught ge {message: 'not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number', name: 'InvalidValueError', stack: 'Error\n    at new ge (https://maps.googleapis.com/m…tp://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:82399:27)
```

The latitude and longitude are numbers only, still getting this error.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most recent release added validation in a couple locations that catches some invalid duck typing of LatLng.

Likely you are passing an object somewhere that has `.lat()` and `.lng()` but is not a LatLng or a subclass of LatLng. This is invalid.

Instead you should pass a LatLngLiteral with an object have `lat` and `lng` properties and number values.